# Computing interval between dates gives #VALUE error even though the columns are in date format

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, ms-office

I have 2 date columns - both have the date format under "number type".
However when I do interval with =C2-B2, I get error.  Under show calculation I get

```
"9/4/2015" - 42252
```

The column that gives me 42252 is in the date format.  I even inserted a new column, changed the format to DATE and typed in a date and it gave me the same error.

I even tried DATEDIF( start_date, end_date, interval ) and it gave me the error.

Comment: that is because 9/4/2015 is 42251.  Subtracting 42252 get -1 and dates cannot be negative.  So flip your calculation or surround it with ABS().

Comment: if i flip it around i get the same error - but it says 42252 - "9/4/2015"

Comment: Change both columns to "General" and make sure that both change to a number around 42000.

Answer (score 1):

If `"9/4/2015"` is text, use the worksheet's [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252) to achieve a real date and not text-that-looks-like-a-date. Using text in any mathematical operation will result in a #VALUE! error.

An Excel date can be considered **1** for every day past 31-Dec-1899. That makes `9/4/2015` (04-Sep-2015) equal to `42251`. By logical extension, `42552` would equal `9/5/2015` (05-Sep-2015).

```
42251 - 42252 = -1
```

Excel does not recognize negative dates; it will return a long series of hashmarks (e.g. ######################). Format the cell as a number to receive `-1`.

When using [DATEDIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c), the start date must precede the end date. DATEDIF will not return a negative number; it will throw a #NUM! error instead.

Answer (score 0):

If there are quotation marks in C2, you'll need something like this

`=SUBSTITUTE(C2,CHAR(34),"")-B2`